# When dual wielding with one cursed weapon, which attacks get the penalty?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, weapons, curses

If a character is dual-wielding short swords and one is cursed, does the second attack occur at −2, or is the curse satiated for that turn once the cursed sword is used?

Comment: What curse does the weapon have on it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to RPG.SE! I am Closing your post for the time being as it unclear *which* curse is being applied. When you get a chance edit this post with the specific curse you're referring to and we can answer your question! also if you get a chance, the [tour] is a great way to learn about how this site works and how it's different from other RPG references you may have encountered.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** I am answering with a very general response, due to the unspecified nature of the question.

Your question is a bit difficult to answer without context or specific curse description, but the general answer is "**every attack**." Curses (usually) inflict a negative magical state on the wielder, not on the item itself. If a weapon only affected its own attacks, it would simply be part of the weapon statistics (i.e. -2 Shortsword) or **be explicitly stated**, not a "curse."

Comment: If you don't feel the question has enough context to answer, it's much better not to answer the question. Flagging it for closure is a much better choice and helps us improve site quality.

Comment: I firmly disagree with downvoting an answer to a question that, however lacking, clearly has community interest. There are people who view this question as valid and in need of an answer, so answering it to the best of my ability in its given form is hardly a disservice to anyone.

Comment: There are many *layers* of community interest. Quality is one of the higher layers that overrides others, because lack of question quality has large-scale, long-term disservice effects.

Comment: That's a fair point; I'll keep it in mind in the future. But for this question, which I see as borderline, I will keep my answer in place in the hope that it helps those who upvoted the question - until closure or improvement.

Comment: I do find it amusing that, whether or not the question had been more specific, answers that cover the general case tend to get more upvotes and be accepted more often.

Comment: The general case is - for good or bad - by definition helpful to more people. And since each person it helps gets one vote, regardless of how valuable the answer was (specific answers being more helpful to less people, but less helpful to others), general answers get more responses. I promise that wasn't my intent! XD

Comment: *pokes head into Wannabe's profile* yeah, thought so, this isn't your first Stack.  Here there's no such thing as a "borderline" case - if a question **could** be unclear or too broad, in any reading by any person ever, then it is.  End of story.  At least, that's been my experience.  You got my last upvote, anyway.